# Asterisk: Unable to save call details in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, asterisk, cdr

I am having trouble in saving my cdr to database. The database connections are fine. I am able to insert data into my table using `INSERT` statements manually but the call records are not being saved automatically as the Asterisk tutorial suggests. I have used the following guide:

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/MSSQL+CDR+Backend

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

1) check by isql that you have connection on odbc level

```
 isql database_entry_in_odbc_ini
```

2) check that you CAN insert cdr via odbc and table structure is correct.

3) check

```
 asterisk -r
 cdr odbc show status
```

4) enable debug in asterisk and see what exactly dooing when call end.

Comment: I am able to save CDR but for ANSWERED calls only. I need to do it for MISSED calls.
I have set unanswered=yes in cdr.conf. Kindly suggest.

Comment: you need restart cdr module or asterisk after change.